# Help cleaning Ubuntu 22.04 with flatpak

Tags: gnome, 22.04, flatpak

Hi these days im cleaning my ubuntu 22.04 system, that has been upgraded from 20.04, which was upgraded from 18.04 which cames from 16.04 … Just to clean as much as i can, and to learn new things.

My problem is that i face this flatpak list:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ flatpak list
Nombre                                           ID de aplicación                                Versión            Rama             Instalación
Pidgin                                           im.pidgin.Pidgin                                2.14.10            stable           system
FileZilla                                        org.filezillaproject.Filezilla                  3.60.1             stable           system
Freedesktop Platform                             org.freedesktop.Platform                        21.08.15           21.08            system
Mesa                                             org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default             21.1.8             20.08            system
Mesa                                             org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default             21.3.9             21.08            system
Intel                                            org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                               20.08            system
Intel                                            org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                               21.08            system
openh264                                         org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264               2.1.0              2.0              system
GNOME Application Platform version 41            org.gnome.Platform                                                 41               system
GNOME Application Platform version 42            org.gnome.Platform                                                 42               system
Polari                                           org.gnome.Polari                                42.1               stable           system
Materia-light GTK theme                          org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Materia-light                                    3.22             system
```

So can i remove Mesa packages and dont break my system ? I know that for example with snaps, i can delete and if this deletion affects other software or packages it warns me before deleting:

```
 me@me:~$ sudo snap remove core18
        core18 removed
   
 me@me:~$ sudo snap remove core20
    error: cannot remove "core20": snap "core20" is not removable: snap is being used by snaps discord,
           firefox, gnome-3-38-2004, snap-store, snapd-desktop-integration and 1 more.
```

So from these packages my logic says that i have to maintein:

```
GNOME Application Platform version 41            org.gnome.Platform                                                 41               system
GNOME Application Platform version 42            org.gnome.Platform
```

Because as far as i know ubuntu 22.04.1 uses gnome 42 and many applications are in gnome 41 still.

But only mythoughts, perhaps i could delete safely 41.
I dont know what to do with:

```
Freedesktop Platform                             org.freedesktop.Platform                        21.08.15           21.08            system
Mesa                                             org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default             21.1.8             20.08            system
Mesa                                             org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default             21.3.9             21.08            system
Intel                                            org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                               20.08            system
Intel                                            org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel                               21.08            system
openh264                                         org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264               2.1.0              2.0              system
```

Also i found, which suggests that i could safely delete/uninstall these packages:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ flatpak uninstall --unused


        ID                                            Rama           Op
 1.     org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default           20.08          r
 2.     org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel          20.08          r
 3.     org.gnome.Platform                            41             r
 4.     org.gnome.Platform.Locale                     41             r

¿Proceder con estos cambios en la instalación del sistema? [Y/n]:
```

Just more info:

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ flatpak history
Hora            Cambio        Aplicación                Rama   Instalación Remoto
sep  4 12:01:26 deploy update im.pidgin.Pidgin.Locale   stable system      flathub
sep  4 12:01:26 deploy update im.pidgin.Pidgin          stable system      flathub
sep  4 12:01:26 uninstall     org.gnome.Platform.Locale 40     system
sep  4 12:01:26 uninstall     org.gnome.Platform        40     system
```

As you could guess i have only one remote flathub.

```
eduardo@MiPcLinux:~$ flatpak list --app
Nombre           ID de aplicación                      Versión        Rama          Instalación
Pidgin           im.pidgin.Pidgin                      2.14.10        stable        system
FileZilla        org.filezillaproject.Filezilla        3.60.1         stable        system
Polari           org.gnome.Polari                      42.1           stable        system
```

Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Do you clean up just to clean up? Otherwise, remove what you do not need anymore. `flatpak remove` is the correct command for flatpak. Using correct commands will never break your system. It will just remove applications or funtionality, which can be restored if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flatpak uninstall --unused` to get rid of all unused versions. You should be asked for confirmation before the real action starts.

Also maybe some flatpaks will be show as "pinned" - this means they will not be uninstalled automatically. You will have to explicitly uninstall them with something like `flatpak uninstall my.flatpak.package` - if those packages are a dependency of another package, the removal still will be denied.

Comment: So i can safely delete all unused packages ? And what about Mesa and Intel packages ?? I dont know where they came from....

Comment: As you wrote that question, I immediately tried to clean up my system here (also 22.04, upgraded from 21.10 just recently). Had similar packages there - just more as I not only used the LTS versions. Mesa and Intel packages seem to be dependencies of the Freedesktop Platform and will stay or leave together with that.

Comment: But i guess you only need one Mesa and one Intel package ..isnt it....?? also you deleted all  unused pakages ?1.     org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default           20.08          r
 2.     org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel          20.08          r
 3.     org.gnome.Platform                            41             r
 4.     org.gnome.Platform.Locale                     41             r ??

Comment: it cleaned everything but the latest version for me. Looks like Flatpaks also have dependencies between each other and the uninstall unused takes care of them.